# Can't Access Class from ASMX Service

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, asmx

I have a class

```
Public Class NotifierAuthHeader
    Inherits SoapHeader

    Public HandlerId As Integer
    Public Guid As Byte()
End Class
```

which I use in webservice in following methods:

```
<OperationContract()><WebMethod()> _
public Function GetTestNotifierAuthHeader()
    Dim testNotifierAuthHeader as NotifierAuthHeader=new NotifierAuthHeader()

    return testNotifierAuthHeader
```

and

```
<SoapHeader("auth", GetType(NotifierAuthHeader), Direction:=SoapHeaderDirection.In)> _
    <OperationContract()> <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetUnreadInboxMessages(ByVal handlerId As Integer, ByVal customerGuid As String) As String
```

The problem is, I can't compile client `WPF` application which has this webservice as servicereference, because it say me, that he doesn't know any `NotifierAuthHeader` class.

```
private ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient _ws = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();

//Here it says about this error

private ServiceReference1.NotifierAuthHeader _authHdr;
```

Funny thing is, that I can use `GetTestNotifierAuthHeader` method at client, but type of return object is..object, not `NotifierAuthHeader`

What could be wrong with my code?

asmx service is 3.5 
and `wpf` app is 4.0 c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your your NotifierAuthHeader serializable

```
<Serializable()>Public Class NotifierAuthHeader 
    Inherits SoapHeader 

    Public HandlerId As Integer 
    Public Guid As Byte() 
End Class
```